# c++ compare vector<string> x to string s

Tags: c++, string, c++11, vector, string-comparison

I am trying to compare a string in a vector to another string:

I tried:

```
vector<string> x;
string y;

if(x[i] == y)
if(x[i].compare(y) == 0)
if(y.compare(x[i]) == 0)
if(x.at(i) == y)
if(x.at(i).compare(y) == 0)
if(y.compare(x.at(i)) == 0)
```

tried passing `x[i]` / `x.at(i)` to `string z` first, nothing. I get no compile errors, no problems, it just seems the vector at index i does not want to compare?

```
g++ -v 4.9.3
Windows 7: cygwin64
c++11, compiling using the -std=c++11 call
```

I print both strings out, they are identical, but it does not want to compare them.

------- source cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

vector<string> get_file(const char* file){
      int SIZE=256, ln=0;
      char str[SIZE];
      vector<string> strs;
      ifstream in(file, ios::in);
      if(!in){
        return strs;
      } else {
        while(in.getline(str,SIZE)){
          strs.push_back(string(str));
          ln++;
        }
      }
      in.close();
      return strs;
    }

void convert_file(const char* file){
      vector<string> s = get_file(file);

      vector<string> d;
      int a, b;
      bool t = false;
      for(int i=0; i<s.size(); i++){
        string comp = "--";
        string m = s.at(i);
        cout << m << endl;
        if(m == comp){  //test string compare
          cout << "s[i] == '--'" << endl;
        }
      }
    }

int main(){
  convert_file("dvds.txt");
  return 0;
}
```

----- dvds.txt

```
--
title:The Shawshank Redemption
director:Stephan King
release_date:14-10-1994
actors:Tim Robbins,Morgan Freeman,Bob Guton
genres:Crime,Drama
rating:R
price:4.99

--
title:Test title
director:Stephan King
release_date:10-10-1990
actors:Morgan Freeman,random 2,random 4
genres:Adventure,Comedy
rating:PG-13
price:4.99



--
title:Test 3
director:None
release_date:15-52-516
actors:Tim Robbins,None,None 2
genres:Crime,Comedy
rating:PG-17
price:4.99
--
```

---- running

```
C:\drew\projects>g++ -o a -std=c++11 source.cpp
C:\drew\projects>a
```

---

prints out the dvds.txt just fine, but no comparison is being done when it should

Comment: If you get no problems them what do you mean it doesn't "want" to compare?

Comment: Print out x[i] and y and make sure they really are (or are not) the same. Or look at them side by side in gdb.

Comment: Please post a minimal working example of code that exhibit the problem.

Comment: `&& false` will cause the if statement never to enter. What is it there for?

Comment: It was to block it out temporarily, the last else if (m == comp) was to test to make sure it was working, it does not. Was heading out the door just quickly copy/pasted it. fixed that && false

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
  std::vector<std::string> x;
  std::string y("AAAA");
  x.push_back("AAAA");

  int i = 0;

  if (x[i] == y) {
    std::cout << y << std::endl;
  }


  return 0;
}
```

It works for me. You might want to double check your variables and their types. You might also want to try the same thing with a different compiler.

Comment: so I did what you did here exactly, and using namespace std, removing std, and swapping out y("AAA") to y = "AAA". All of which works. in a test file, using -std=c++11

Comment: Glad to be of help :)

Comment: it does not fix my problem, but I do think I know where the problem actually is. I am filling the string from a txt file line by line, when it does this its going into a char[] first, I think I need to convert the char[] array to a string first.

Comment: If you are reading from a text file, you might want to look at file streams http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/ and string streams http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/ this way you do not need to convert a char[] to a string.